# JSON array Iteration in typescript - Identifier Expected

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, interface

I am trying to iterate through the json array in typescript.

For understanding I wrote basic example with interface person.

I am getting Identifier Expected issue on the following line:

**isArray(curr[k]) ? curr.[k]?.[0] : curr[k],**.

***ERROR: Identifier expected***

Code ahead:

```
import { isArray } from 'lodash'; 


const myObj = {
  "allData" :{
   "person" : [
    {
        "name":"John", 
        "age":30, 
        "email":"djsbjb"
    },
    {
        "name":"rohit.sharma.my.name", 
        "age":20, 
        "email":"fdbfhdbfn"
    }
   ]
  }
  };

interface Person {
  name: String,
  age: number,
  email?: String
}

const example = (
  person: Person
) => {
  //rohit,sharma,my,name"
  const k = myObj.allData.person[1].name.split(
    '.'
    ) as (keyof typeof person)[];

  console.log(`output of k: ${k}`);
  const curr = { ...person};
  console.log(`output of curr: ${curr}`);
  if (!curr) {
    return;
  } 

  const ans =  k.map((k) => 
    isArray(curr[k]) ? curr.[k]?.[0] : curr[k],
  ); 

  return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Optional chaining to access array indices is not valid syntax:

For example if you had

```js
const object: { [key in string]?: string[] } = { key: ['a'] }

const value = object.key?[0] // this is not valid
```

Instead, use `&&` to conditionally access array elements if the array is not null or undefined:

```js
const object: { [key in string]?: string[] } = { key: ['a'] }

const value = object.key && object.key[0]
```

In your case update it like follows:

```js
  const ans =  k.map((k) => 
    curr[k] && isArray(curr[k]) ? curr[k][0] : curr[k],
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I updated the code and now I am getting the following errors:
on line : curr[k][0]
ERROR: 
Object is possibly 'undefined'